# R: The difference between two points from the plot for log x axis

Tags: r

I need to calculate the time difference of the each sample (the samples can be differentiated using ID column) between two temperature points for log x axis. I get the calculated results, however for linear axis, not log. How can I achieve calculation for log scale using my code:

1. Sample data

   ```
   dput(data)
   structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L),
   Zeit = c(0L, 180L, 360L, 420L, 600L, 604L, 0L, 180L,360L, 480L, 600L,
   605L), Temp = c(963L, 824L, 666L, 658L, 641L,549L, 957L, 823L, 661L,
   660L, 642L, 562L)), .Names = c("id","Zeit", "Temp"), row.names = c(NA,
   12L), class = "data.frame")
   ```
2. Code:

   ```
   Zt <- vapply(unique(data$id), function(ID){
       with(data[data$id == ID,], approx(x = Temp, y = Zeit, xout = 600))$y
   }, double(1))
   data.frame(id = unique(data$id), time = Zt)
   ```

There is an option in `approx` for method. However there are only two methods specified:

- `linear`
- `constant`

and as I mentioned before, the log is what I am looking for

Thanks for help!

**[UPDATE]**

Why log makes difference in my case.

Just for explanation I am going to use small set of data where we can see how log makes the difference:

here is the data:

```
data <-structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Zeit = c(31L, 701L, 902L), 
    Temp = c(930L, 549L, 481L)), .Names = c("id", "Zeit", "Temp"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is plot for it (1st is with log axis, second is normal):

[image]
[image]

if i wanna see for example the time which i need to get to **700°C**, in log scale it would be equal to around **200** sec, for normal one it is equal to around **325** sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use `approx()`. But you need to do a couple of things to get the behaviour you want:

1. log transform the input values before passing them to `approx`, and then
2. inverse-log (i.e. `exp`) the answer to convert back to the correct units.

Thus, in your example, to solve for Zeit at Temp=700, by interpolating the log-transformed values of Zeit, this would be

```
exp( approx(x = data$Temp, y = log(data$Zeit), xout = 700))$y )
## 203.6818
```

Comment: Great! It works perfectly! Just for some people who are interested, in the function it looks like this: `Zt <- vapply(unique(data$id), function(ID){
  exp(with(data[data$id == ID,], approx(x = data$Temp, y = log(data$Zeit), xout = 700))$y)
}, double(1))
data.frame(id = unique(data$id), time = Zt)`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: much simpler than mine below! - it seems like approx should offer this functionality though. I'm not capable of hacking the underlying C libraries to make this work, but it would be a nice-to-have.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of preliminary items:

1. Based on the graphs you are displaying below, your `x` and `y` values appear to be reversed in your original code.
2. The function I have here does not have all of the functionality of the `approx()` function in `stats`, but I think it will meet your needs.

To start, consider that the `approx()` function uses a variant of the following formula to produce a result:

**Equation 1:**

[image]

where

- http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?x_%7Bout%7D_ is the point at which interpolation is to take place,
- [image] is the value preceding http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?x_%7Bout%7D_ within `x`,
- [image] is the value following http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?x_%7Bout%7D_ within `x`,
- [image] is the `y` value corresponding to [image],
- [image] is the `y` value corresponding to [image], and
- http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%24y_%7Bout%7D%24 is the `y` value returned by the function.

To return a value of http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%24y_%7Bout%7D%24 which corresponds to a log-scaled x-axis, we simply log the relevant portions of the formula as follows:

**Equation 2:**

[image]

Below I implement both formulas in a new function called `approx_log()`

```
approx_log <- function(x, y, xout){
  
  dat <- data.frame(y=y, x=x)
  dat <- dat[with(dat, order(x, y)), ]
  
  y_in <- dat$y
  x_in <- dat$x
  
  # find the start of our interval
  int_start <- which(x_in == max(x_in[x_in <= xout]))

  # assign the int_start value to x_0 and the 
  # value from the next highest index to x_1
  x_0 <- x_in[int_start]
  x_1 <- x_in[int_start + 1]
  
  # repeat for corresponding y-values 
  y_0 <- y_in[int_start]
  y_1 <- y_in[int_start + 1]
  

  y_out_lin <- y_0 + ((xout-x_0)/(x_1-x_0))*(y_1-y_0)
    
  y_out_log <- y_0 + ((log(xout)-log(x_0))/(log(x_1)-log(x_0)))*(y_1-y_0)
    
  # return values 
  list(x = xout, y_lin = y_out_lin, y_log = y_out_log)
}
```

As can be seen, this function returns a list of http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?x_%7Bout%7D_ and the log and linear interpolation values of http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%24y_%7Bout%7D%24. The code below tests the function based on your visual interpolation in the posting.

```
data <-structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Zeit = c(31L, 701L, 902L), 
    Temp = c(930L, 549L, 481L)), .Names = c("id", "Zeit", "Temp"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

approx_log(x = data$Zeit, y = data$Temp, xout = 200)

## $x
## [1] 200
## 
## $y_lin
## [1] 833.897
## 
## $y_log
## [1] 702.2286
```

As you suggest, the log-scaled version of time at 200 seconds corresponds almost exactly to 700 degrees.

```
approx_log(x = data$Zeit, y = data$Temp, xout = 325)

## $x
## [1] 325
## 
## $y_lin
## [1] 762.8149
## 
## $y_log
## [1] 642.9125
```

The linear version of time at 325 seconds is a little higher (about 763 degrees) but reasonable based on your original plot. As a sanity check, we can see that the linear value matches the `approx()` function exactly.

```
approx(x = data$Zeit, y = data$Temp, xout = 325)

## $x
## [1] 325
## 
## $y
## [1] 762.8149
```

We can also run this through `vapply()` per your original request.

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L),
               Zeit = c(0L, 180L, 360L, 420L, 600L, 604L, 0L, 180L,360L, 480L, 600L,
                        605L), Temp = c(963L, 824L, 666L, 658L, 641L,549L, 957L, 823L, 661L,
                                        660L, 642L, 562L)), .Names = c("id","Zeit", "Temp"), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                           12L), class = "data.frame")

Zt <- vapply(unique(data$id), function(ID){
  with(data[data$id == ID,], approx_log(y = Temp, x = Zeit, xout = 325))$y_log
}, double(1))
data.frame(id = unique(data$id), time = Zt)

##   id     time
## 1  1 689.3140
## 2  2 684.9043
```

You could seperately extract the `y_lin` value for the sake of comparison.

```
Zt <- vapply(unique(data$id), function(ID){
  with(data[data$id == ID,], approx_log(y = Temp, x = Zeit, xout = 325))$y_lin
}, double(1))
data.frame(id = unique(data$id), time = Zt)

##   id     time
## 1  1 696.7222
## 2  2 692.5000
```

**EDIT**
The original question sought to solve for Zeit, given Temp (i.e. solve for x, given y).  The above code solves for log-interpolated values of y, for a given x.  The inverse of this is achieved by re-arranging Equation 2 to solve for x_out.  The function for this, as provided in a comment by @joemienko is

```
x_out_log <- exp((yout*log(x_0)-y_1*log(x_0)-yout*log(x_1)+y_0*log(x_1))/(y_0-y_1))
```

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks! However smthg in Your code is not working properly. I need to find out the time which is needed till temp =700°C, so it has to be: `approx_log(y = data$Zeit, x = data$Temp, xout = 700)`. And here unfortunatelly comes an error: ` Error in findInterval(xout, x_in) : 
  'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs` (there is no NAs in this small data)..

Comment: Ok - I have edited the function so you can now send in an x value of any order (that was my problem previously). However, you should make sure that you really want to reverse these. The function is applying the log transformation to whatever variable is specified as x. If you set x = Temp, then the transform is being applied to Temp and Zeit is untransformed. I suspect that what you really want to do is specify a y-value as a point of interpolation and "solve" for x. I need to go to work now, but I can try to implement something like this later today.

Comment: If you want to give the "solve for x" approach a whirl in the interim, I think this formula ought to do it: `x_out_log <- exp((yout*log(x_0)-y_1*log(x_0)-yout*log(x_1)+y_0*log(x_1))/(y_0-y_1))`

Comment: As you can see, we'd need to add a `yout` parameter to the function and then implement some parameter checking within the function to see whether or not the user specified `yout` or `xout`, but not both.

Comment: i really apprecieate Your answer with all this explanation. it is really great! However again the values which i got were wrong(i used your new approx_log function for the small data-this with only 3 rows- `approx_log(y = data$Zeit, x = data$Temp, xout = 700)`, and i got `$x
[1] 700

$y_lin
[1] 435.4619

$y_log
[1] 392.1361`, whereas the plotted above graph shows that y_log should be around 200

Comment: @dww, not likely to get to this for another couple of days. Dissertation calls.